# How to insert line break in md-list-item *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, line-breaks, listitem

I'm making a md-list with an iteration of an array. My code:

```js
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
  fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

  <div fxFlex="40">
    <md-card>
      <md-card-header>
        <md-card-title>
          <h3>{{ dish.name | uppercase }}</h3>
        </md-card-title>
      </md-card-header>
      <img md-card-image src="{{dish.image}}" alt="{{dish.name}}">
      <md-card-content>
        <p>
          {{dish.description}}
        </p>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions>
        <button md-button>LIKE</button>
        <button md-button>SHARE</button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex="40" *ngIf="dish">
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item>
        <h3>Comments</h3>
      </md-list-item>
      <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of dish.comments">
        <p>{{item.comment}}</p>
        <p>{{item.rating + " Stars"}}</p>
        <p>{{item.author}} {{item.date}}</p>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </div>

</div>
```

What I expect:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM4uC.png)

What I get:

[Result got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHcVi.png)

And here is my constant with the array:

[Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgGhC.png)

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried with ,  for each comment, rating and author, dxLayout="row" next to *ngFor, but I got nothing. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can use the class `dishComment` to set the space between each `dish.comments`

```
<md-list-item *ngFor="let item of dish.comments">
    <div class='dishComment'>
        <li>{{item.comment}}</li>
        <li>{{item.rating + " Stars"}}</li>
        <li>{{item.author}} {{item.date}}</li>
    </div>
 </md-list-item>
```

Css

```
.dishComment li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: Now it shows each block of comment, rating and author in different columns.

Comment: I've tried this: <div fxFlex="40" *ngIf="dish">
    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <md-list *ngFor="let item of dish.comments">
      <md-list-item>{{item.comment}}</md-list-item>
      <md-list-item> {{item.rating + " Stars"}}</md-list-item>      
      <md-list-item>{{item.author}} {{item.date}}
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </div>

Comment: remove the space using css

Comment: <div fxFlex="40" *ngIf="dish">
    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <md-list *ngFor="let item of dish.comments">
      <div class='dishComment'>
      <md-list-item>{{item.comment}}</md-list-item>
      <md-list-item> {{item.rating + " Stars"}}</md-list-item>      
      <md-list-item>{{item.author}} {{item.date}}</md-list-item>
    </div>
    </md-list>
  </div>
</div>
in the scss:

.dishComment md-list-item{
    list-style-type:none;
  }

Comment: Like this? I get confused when mixing css and Angular